# Simple HTML DOM Stops When It Cant Find Table

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

I'm using the following code to grab some data from a table, but if the table doesn't exist, my entire script just stops. Im not firmilar with adding checks if something exists with this, or is there something else I should do instead?

```
if(($salary->find('table.rc_table_name') != null)){
$table02 = $salary->find('table.table_name');
$rows2 = $table02[0]->find('td.table_td');

foreach( $rows2 as $row ){
$getjobs3 = $row->find('td.table_td');
$getjobs33 = $getjobs3[0]->plaintext;

$jobspast .= "$getjobs33";

}}    

foreach($table02[0]->find('td.table_td') as $element2) {

$uri3 = explode( "\n", $element2->plaintext );
$uri03 = $uri3[0];
$uri13 = $uri3[1];
$slug2 = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '-', strtolower($uri3[0]));
$slug2 = substr($slug2, 1, -1);

$jobspast .= '<a href="'.$slug2.'">'.$uri03.'</a>'.$uri13.'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, had to set as null before finding the object, and using if != null.